# how to compare some part of a string in c?

Tags: c, string, compare

I have a question about compare only some part of a string

For example:

```
char *string = "nameOfPeople_Allen";

char searchName[20] = "Allen";
```

how to trim the `char *string = "nameOfPeople_Allen";`from `_` to get the name `Allen`, then compare it with `searchName`, I know how to compare string, but how to get the last part of the `"nameOfPeople_Allen"` from `_`?

Comment: Search for `'_'` character, `strchr()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `strchr()`

```
char *pointer;
if ((pointer = strchr(string, '_')) != NULL)
 {
    printf("The text after _ is %s\n", pointer + 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strstr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) standard library function.

```
char *temp = strstr(string, "Allen");
```

then use `strcmp` to compare it with `searchName`.

To find the sub-string after `-` use `strchr`

```
char *temp = strchr(string, '_');   
if(temp)  
    printf("%s\n", temp+1);
```

Comment: how about if the char *string = "nameOfPeople_Allen"; is char *string = "nameOfPeople_AllenAllen";, looks like there are not the same name

Comment: @ratzip; Read about `strstr`.

Comment: From OP *I know how to compare string, but how to get the last part of the "nameOfPeople_Allen" from _*. Your code doesn't help him to *get the last part of the "nameOfPeople_Allen" from _* but find occurrence of string `"Allen"` which doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil; OK. Done.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and fast way:

```
// static inline if you are interested
int sameName(const char *string, const char *searchName) {
    const char *p;
    return (p = strchr(string, '_')) && strcmp(p+1, searchName) == 0;
}
```

Comment: How you concluded that its a fast way?

Comment: Both `strchr()` and `strcmp()` are very simple `O(n)` functions. Function `strstr()` seems to be `O(n*m)` if I understant code right. It could be done `O(n+m)` using some advanced algorithms but it seems not be used in standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As for *trimming*, whatever you do, **don't** modify `string` as it is allocated in read-only memory. (You can help yourself here by using `const char* string`)

But you *can* use `strstr` to check for containment:

```
if (strstr(string, "Allen"))...
```

Comment: Could you explain why it is allocated in r-o memory, and what it is?

Comment: Because it's a string literal and C works that way. Attempting to modify the string is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to loop trough it for some reason, try this:

```
int i, check = 0, position = 0;
char part_of_string[20];
for(i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++){
    if(check){ 
         part_of_string[position] = string[i];
         position++;
    }else if(string[i] == '_'){
         check = 1;
    }
}
```

Now `part_of_string` contains the chars after the '_' character. You could compare it with `strcmp()` or loop through it again to check for "Alan".